# How to print the name of document that during the reading to pandas data frame displays the warning

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I have this warning  during the reading excel document to data frame:

*

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Slobo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6211
    sort=sort)
FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.
To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.
To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.
```

*

For reading all documents from a particular folder I use this:

```
`for f in glob.glob(dirname + "/*.xlsx")`:
    #where dirname is the path to the folder, and then for reading documents:
    pd.read_excel(f)
```

I want to print the name of the document which causes warning appearance during its reading to the data frame.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")

for f in glob.glob(dirname + "/*.xlsx"):
    try:
       pd.read_excel(f)
    except Warning as w:
        print(f)
```

Comment: it doesnot work for me, I donot why...only difference is that I have df = pd.read_excel(f).

Comment: -there is no error, just displays warning again without print the name of document.

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: Now appears "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slobo\Desktop\Python\Project\Export\import.py", line 63, in <module>
    df = df.append(df,ignore_index=True)..." because I append all documents in one data frame, and after that displays the same warning, but interrupts script execution, because of error.

Comment: I succeded...I put:
*import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")

for f in glob.glob(dirname + "/*.xlsx"):
    try:
       df = pd.read_excel(f)
       df = df.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    except Warning as w:
        print(f)*

Comment: Maybe edit your post saying you tried this and wait for a better answer

Comment: @Omakar- No, everything is fine, everything works. Thank you very much.